# different proof Inner product is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

For a homework assignment I'm asked to prove that several functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous in two ways:

i):using the coordinates and the definition of continuity

ii): using the coordinates and appropriate theorems

for instance, one such function was the inner function $f\to \langle a,x\rangle$ for some fixed element $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

for i) I don't see any problems, just use Cauchy-Schwarz to conclude that $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{|a|}$, then $|\langle a,x\rangle-\langle a,y\rangle|<|a|\delta=\epsilon$.

However, I do not see any way to conclude that $\langle a,x\rangle$ is continuous in any other way. I was working towards an idea of that for a continuous $f=(f_1,...f_n)$, any function in $f_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ is continuous, but I keep getting stuck on how to use this to prove something like this, without reverting to the same technique used in i). Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: MathJax tip: `\langle` and `\rangle` look better for inner products than `<` and `>`. For example, `$\langle a, x \rangle$` looks like $\langle a, x \rangle$, while `$<a,x>$` looks like $<a,x>$.

Comment: thank you, I will edit it straight away. Any comments on the substance?

Comment: Nothing too helpful, I'm afraid. It's a little difficult to see what your lecturer intends with these two questions. Your method (which I agree is the superior method) uses both theorems (Cauchy-Schwarz) and the definition of continuity, so it seems appropriate for both parts? Perhaps your lecturer intends you to expand out the dot product, and argue that $a \cdot x = a_1 x_1 + \ldots + a_n x_n$ is a linear combination of continuous functions? It's difficult to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you, I think this could work! It seems quite obvious come to think of it.

Comment: I suppose your lecturer wanted something along the line: $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^n\xrightarrow{A}\mathbb{R}^n\xrightarrow{\sum}\mathbb{R}$ is the composition of two continuous maps.  $A$ is multiplying each coordinates by appropriate $a_i$ (continuity from product in $\mathbb{R}$), $\sum$ is sum (continuity by induction on $n$).

Comment: Also, regarding the C-S proof, make sure you treat the $a = 0$ case separately.

Comment: @TheoBendit yes, my reasoning was that $|\langle a,x\rangle-\langle a,y\rangle|=0$ if $a=0$ which then holds for any $\epsilon>0$.